# Can we map continuous function to formal power series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

As the title suggested, I want to construct a map from continuous function of compact interval to formal power series. Since every continuous function is infinite sum of polynomials, the map will rearrange them into power series(since the sum of polynomials may not be absolute convergence, the power series may diverges), and map it to formal power series.

The problem I concern is can we really rearrange them, and is there any need to rearrange them. I don't know if the expression $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}p_{i}(X)$, where $p_{i}(X)$ are polynomial of $X$, are elements of the ring of formal power series.

Comment: Of course you can map continuous functions to formal power series, for example define $m(f)=0$ for every continuous function $f$. It seems you want the power series to converge to the function - no, you can't do that, since the sum of a convergent power series is smooth. (No, a sum of polynomials need not be a power series.)

Comment: Do sum of polynomials differ from power series by rearrangement?

Comment: A sum of polynomials differs from a power series in not being a power series. A power series is $\sum a_nz^n$; a sum of polynomials is in general not $\sum a_nz^n$.